# Will there be a way to install "Ubuntu for phones" on Apple mobile devices?

Tags: apple, ubuntu-touch, phone, smartphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

Is there any plans to make Ubuntu Phone OS run on jailbroken iPads, iPhones, and iPods? I know someone managed to get Xubuntu running on an iPod touch once so I was wondering if Ubuntu's Phone OS will run on iDevices.

Comment: If someone managed once, it possibly could be done, though don't bank on it. As Web-E said, it is unlikely. Have a look at the [required phone specifications](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/operators-and-oems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it won't. Jailbrocken iDevice are only just having root access the device.

The bootloader to these devices are locked and they will only boot iOS.

And also the android phones whose bootloader are locked can't install it.

Comment: Would it be able to work with this? [iDroid project](http://www.idroidproject.org/)

Comment: Those are very old iDevices as I can see.Ubuntu for phone doesn't meet the hardware spec. Even if there is way to replace the bootloader, you need to create drivers for the iOS devices. Without 0 source code of them (without knowing the hardware details, as apple hardly disclose them), it will be very hard to implement. Ubuntu devs can't do so because of legal action.